# boost::asio::read_at : any example?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

I am trying to use the [`boost::asio::read_at`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_at.html) method with socket. I cant find any example around it ...

I am trying to read a single int32 from the socket stream. I thought this could work :

```
char * g = get_buf();
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket * sock = get_socket();
boost::asio::read_at(*sock, 4, boost::asio::buffer( g, 4));
/* convert char[4] to int ... */
```

but I get the error:

```
    error C2039: 'read_some_at' : is not a member of  boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<Protocol>'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is 7k lines of test code in **[libs/asio/test/read_at.cpp](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/master/test/read_at.cpp)**

I hope that is enough to give you an idea about what is supported and what the expected outcome is.

I'd say it should likely only work with random access devices though

Comment: Your link is not related to socket, and this is my problem. But thanks anyway.

Comment: So, waiting for random people on the internet to write it for you isn't time consuming? I've looked some more at it, and I'm convinced `read*_at` is only implemented for **[`(basic_)random_access_handle(_service)` (Windows specific)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html)**. So, you simply cannot use it for sockets. You **can** use buffer arithmetic though (the responsibility for range checking is on the caller though): http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html#boost_asio.reference.buffer.buffer_arithmetic

Comment: @norisknofun `read_at` is not related to your problem :) It's not "my link", it's "your question" that set the topic!

Comment: I can wait for this part since I have a lot more work to do ! `read_at` is kind of a trap, do not use it. My advice for the ones trying to use `read_at` : use the basic socket::read_some and rebuild the complete buffer. Wouaw, boost::asio is so usefull ! ;)

Comment: Well. I'm puzzled why you asked then. Also, wondering whether my answer helped in any way. Finally, it would be nice to have your arguments for calling `read_at` a trap. If it's a trap like a siren luring you into using it, I'll submit that [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_at.html) simply state that you need a `SyncRandomAccessReadDevice` to use this with.